# Android BitmapRegionDecoder decodeRegion NullPointerException on 10" tablet

Tags: android, bitmap, nullpointerexception

In my Android app I'm using the following code:

```
BitmapRegionDecoder decoder;
...
decoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(myStream, false);
...
int width = -1, height = -1, left = -1, top = -1;
...
Log.d("GDA", left + " " + top + " " + width + " " + height);
Rect re = new Rect(left, top, width, height);
Log.d("GDA", re.toString());
if(decoder != null)
    region = decoder.decodeRegion(re, null);
```

everything work well on smartphones and 7" tablets but in 10" tablets (I tested it on a Samsung GT10.1 and an Acer A501) I got this error:

```
1152 1728 2304 2592
Rect(1152, 1728 - 2304, 2592)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.graphics.BitmapRegionDecoder.decodeRegion(BitmapRegionDecoder.java:399)
```

I can't find a solution. Has anyone had the same issue? Any suggestions?

Comment: My app has the same issue, any new developments on yours?  Works on a GTP5113 with 4.1.1 -- fails on GT-P7310 with 4.0.4. I create a BitmapRegionDecoder using decodeRegion to slice my bitmap. Something broken then fixed between releases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution:

Don't use "region = decoder.decodeRegion(re, null);", use for example:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
region = decoder.decodeRegion(re, options);
```

It's work, checked for Galaxy Tab 10.1 Android 4.0.x